# Web-based Outlook add-in to read and process message contents

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office365, outlook-addin, office365-apps

I want to create a web based Outlook Add-in which does not run in the context of a message or appointment. I simply thought about a new group with one button on the home tab. On click, a new window should be shown.
In platform-dependent concepts (like vsto) this was possible. But it seems that this scenario isn´t supported by the new web concepts. At least not in outlook.

The program should run more like a service and observe the outbox and read (extract and transform) and prepare specific messages (maybe archive their contents locally - which is another problem because of the sandbox mechanism).

I want to deploy to windows and mac desktop clients.

**Is that even possible?**
**Is a [module extension](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/extension-module-outlook-add-ins?product=outlook) an alternative? (Is it supported on mac?)**

Comment: Hi did you ever figure this out? I'm researching different possibilities with a similar goal.  I don't want it to run in the context of any individual email.  Instead I want it to run in the Context of a folder.  I actually have much of the UI done and functional - think of a VERY custom [from the ground-up] re-do of your inbox view - so it works with a list of emails, not individual emails.  The entry-point to that UI is where I'm scratching my head - everything seems to be in the context of a message.  Module Exts seem to be limited to Outlook2016 on Windows ONLY (from what I can tell). Thx

Answer (score 1):

Task Panes and contextual Custom Panes are designed to interact with the selected/open message.  You can define add-in commands (custom Ribbon buttons: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/define-add-in-commands) that run a JavaScript function in your defined .html page.  These functions can do whatever you want and don't necessarily have to interact with the message or Mailbox whatsoever.

However there is no feature that allows you to run a background application - your custom code always has to be executed by the user.  The alternative is to use the Graph API (or Exchange Web Services) in a web server or client application context.

A module extension is similar to add-in commands, but by default doesn't run in the context of any message.  Module extensions are essentially just a canvas for displaying web pages, but you have access to the Mailbox API.